# problemas con el router link

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, css3

tengo una aplicacion de angular y css
este es el codigo

```
<section class="section section--menu" id="Valentine">
<h2 class="section__title">Valentine</h2>
<span class="link-copy"></span>
<nav class="menu menu--valentine">
    <ul class="menu__list">
        <li class="menu__item" [routerLink]="[ '/home' ]" routerLinkActive="menu__item--current"><a  class="menu__link" >Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item" [routerLink]="[ '/nosotros' ]" routerLinkActive="menu__item--current"><a  class="menu__link">Shop</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item" [routerLink]="[ '/producto' ]" routerLinkActive="menu__item--current"><a class="menu__link">Reviews</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item" [routerLink]="[ '/productos' ]" routerLinkActive="menu__item--current"><a class="menu__link">News</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item" [routerLink]="[ '/shop' ]" routerLinkActive="menu__item--current"><a class="menu__link">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

todo funciona normal pero hay algo que no puedo manejar , ***cuando hago click a un boton me aparece este marco negro a rededor de el boton como un outline negro que no deberia de estar*** eh intentado sacarlo por css de varias maneras pero sin resultados, cabe mencionar que en una pagina normal html simple no ocurre este error solo me da cuando aplico a mi nav a un proyecto de angular
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas usando estilos de algun framework o son los tuyos?

Comment: Puedes compartir el css de ese componente, específicamente la clase "menu__item--current", o si es algún framework que estas utilizando para la vista, porfavor

Comment: Puede deberse a las lineas routerLinkActive que tienes y ademas a que tienes un elemento <a> dentro de tus li, ten en cuenta que routerLink funciona como un elemento <a> en si cuando lo pones, por lo que poner una etiqueta <a> en ese caso esta demas, los elementos <a> por defecto tienen decoracion.

Comment: Despues de investigar encontre una solucion.
es desabilitar la prodiedad focus a todos los elementos.
*:focus { 
outline: none;
 }   @Riven

Answer (score 0):

Despues de investigar encontre una solucion.
es desabilitar la prodiedad focus a todos los elementos.

```
*:focus { 
outline: none;
 }
```